# Change background color of a cell based on text for multiple sheets without manually configuring conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im working in a script to change background cell in Google sheets based on a "name", like:
"If the patient **Jonh Dole** is registered, the cell changes to *LightGreen*; if **Jane Dole** is registered, the cell takes same color."
I used to set conditional format for that, but on every new entry I have to set all sheets manually.

Can you please write me a script to do this or advise me on how to write one myself?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the `Apps Script` feature of Google Sheets to programmatically set the background color for a range of cells based on whether a cell value was present in another sheet. You can open the Apps Script editor from the Google Sheets menu under `Extensions -> App Script`

The solution I came up with uses two functions. The first function extends the `onEdit()` event hook from Google Sheets and filters its execution down to a specific set of fields.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if( ! e ){
    return;
  }
  var currentSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRange = e.range;
  // only want action to occur when a single cell changes
  if( currentRange.getNumRows() === 1 && currentRange.getNumColumns() === 1 ){
    var currentColumn = currentRange.getLastColumn();
    var currentRow = currentRange.getLastRow();
    // only want action to occur for a column on a certain sheet
    var myTargetSheet = "Sheet 1";
    var myTargetColumn = 1;
    if( currentSheet.getName() == myTargetSheet && currentColumn == myTargetColumn ){
      // set background color for the selected row based on a lookup
      var cellValue = currentRange.getCell(1,1).getValue();
      var assignedColor = myCustomSearch( cellValue );
      currentSheet.getRange( "A" + currentRow + ":E" + currentRow ).setBackgroundColor( assignedColor );
    }
  }
}
```

The second function executes a lookup on an adjacent sheet and returns the background color of the matching search term.

```js
function myCustomSearch( searchTerm ){
  var assignedColor = "#ffffff";
  var lookupSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
  var lookupRange = lookupSheet.getRange("H1:H20"); // where the search terms live
  var numColumns = lookupRange.getNumColumns();
  var numRows = lookupRange.getNumRows();
  var lookupList = lookupRange.getValues();
  for( var myColumn=0; myColumn < numColumns; myColumn++ ){
    for( var myRow=0; myRow < numRows; myRow++ ){
      if( lookupList[myRow][myColumn] == searchTerm ){
        assignedColor = lookupSheet.getRange("H"+(myRow+1)).getBackgroundColor();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return assignedColor;
}
```